# movement not working as expected after rotation

Tags: html, canvas, translate

I have a canvas where I work with an image, move, rotate and scale. Everything is working fine until I try to combine all transformations. For example I'm moving the image based on the user mouse movement difference and it's ok but if I rotate the image first to let's say 180 degrees then the image movement is inverted relative to mouse movement. How can I fix that?

```
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 580);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
        ctx.scale(scale, scale);
        ctx.rotate(toRad(angle));
        ctx.translate(-(canvas.width / 2), -(canvas.height / 2));
        ctx.drawImage(image, tx, ty, image.width, image.height);
        ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to post a bit more code if possible, but I believe the issue has to do with your translations. Heres a similiar example, although movement is not dependent on the mouse.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/v86rC/)

```
    // save the context
    ctx.save();
    // translate it to the objects x and y, basically your taking the canvas and moving it to each object.
    ctx.translate(box.x, box.y);
    // now rotate it
    ctx.rotate(box.angle);
    // -5 is half of the box width and height 0,0 is the boxes location, im drawing it at half the width and height to set the rotation origin to the center of the box.
    ctx.fillRect(-5,-5, 10,10); 
    // now restore
    ctx.restore();
```

Your `tx` and `ty` Im assuming are from the mouse coords, well since you have rotated the canvas the `tx` and `ty` are now "rotated".